# Not clickable button with selenium or beautifulSoup

Tags: javascript, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull data from a page, I'm trying to click on the field I have forwarded, but I can't click. How should I proceed, I would be grateful if you could help.

```
<a href="javascript:void;" id="sellerPhoneRevealButton" class="hidden-phone__reveal-button"><i class="hidden-phone__reveal-icon"></i>Einblenden</a>
```

I want to capture the area in the photo I sent, I tried these methods but I can't click. I guess it's a hurdle to start with javascript. How can I progress?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpCh5.png)

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"hidden-phone__reveal-icon").click()

driver.find_element("i", {"class": "hidden-phone__reveal-icon"}).click()

driver.find_element(By.ID,"sellerPhoneRevealButton").click()

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/aside/div[1]/div/div[4]/p/span/a").click()

driver.find_element("span", {"class": "u-inline-block u-text-bold promo clickable"}).click(`)
```

https://suchen.mobile.de/fahrzeuge/details.html?id=349835237&cn=DE&damageUnrepaired=NO_DAMAGE_UNREPAIRED&isSearchRequest=true&makeModelVariant1.makeId=1900&makeModelVariant1.modelId=3&pageNumber=1&scopeId=C&sfmr=false&sortOption.sortBy=specifics.mileage&s

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(
            lambda d: d.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='sc-bczRLJ iBneUr mde-consent-accept-btn']")).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(
            lambda d: d.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[@class='phone-number-container']")).click()
```

This code will fix the problem. Just click on the paragraph there.

Comment: I am grateful for your hard work. However, when I combine it with my own codes, it still draws the number incompletely. Am I doing it wrong, I don't get it anymore. (I keep it as tel_number in other fields, here it gives an error if I don't assign it to the variable.)

Comment: `try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(
            lambda d: d.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='sc-bczRLJ iBneUr mde-consent-accept-btn']")).click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(
            lambda d: d.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[@class='phone-number-container']")).click()
        tel_number = ad_soup.find("span", {"id": ('seller-phone')}).get_text()
    except:
        #tel_number = ' '
        print("NOT found tel number")`

Comment: By.XPATH, "//p[@class='phone-number-container' just use this ve clicked

Comment: Hmm I get it. Finally, if I proceed in this way, how can I print to the tel_number column? because that's how I defined it. If I don't define it, it gives an error that it is not defined.

Comment: It didn't happen that way unfortunately, it just clicks here. It's not pulling data.
:(

Comment: Ok now you should get the Text of the item you clicked. driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[@class='phone-number-container']").text

Comment: I appreciate your help, I edited the code like this but it keeps pulling the numbers half way :(

  try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(
            lambda d: d.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='sc-bczRLJ iBneUr mde-consent-accept-btn']")).click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(
            lambda d: d.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[@class='phone-number-container']")).click()
        tel_number = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[@class='phone-number-container']").text

Comment: I can't thank you enough, it's finally done. Thank youuuu

Comment: I'm glad you succeeded